# How to send zabbix alert containing changed data?

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

Zabbix newbie here. (Using Zabbix 1.8.)

I'm looking for documentation that will help me to configure following alert:

1. Once per 15 minutes check `whois example.com`.
2. If whois info is changed since the last check, send e-mail to `ops@example.net`.
3. E-mail should contain the output of `whois` command that was executed previously (a diff would be cool, but is not necessary).

I'm having trouble with item 3 of the list (and I'm not satisfied with how I implemented item 1, so I'm looking for some hints on the "right" way to do it.) Reading Zabbix docs did not clear things enough for me, unfortunately. Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create UserParameter in zabbix agent on your host, containing outout of `whois` command. https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual/config/user_parameters
- Test new item with `zabbix_get` command
- Create new item for host: type - Zabbix Agent, key - name of your User Parameter
- Create new trigger, monitoring chandging of your item
- Create and configure media type "Email" in Administration - Media Types. You need working mail server
- In Configuration - Actions you should create new action. It's message should include {ITEM.LASTVALUE}
- Add condition to the action: Trigger = your trigger
- Add opetration to the action: send message to your user. User must have configured mail address